# Bash Shell Script Array Length Off By One

Tags: bash, array

The length of an array in my bash shell script appears to be off by one.  I have `11` elements in a text file that I am reading in to an array, but my array length seems to be `12`.

```
(( count = 0 ))
while read students[$count] ; do
    (( count++ ))
done < students.dat

echo $count

ArrayLength=$((${#students[@]}))

echo $ArrayLength
```

This code outputs:

```
11
12
```

The `11` makes sense since the count increment occurs after the read occurs and starts with `0`--indicating `11` elements read in.

But the `12` is mysterious.

Here is the data file:

```
Ann
Bob
Cindy
Dean
Emily
Frank
Ginger
Hal
Ivy
Justin
Karen
```

(names appear on their own lines, but I couldn't format it that way in this post)

I've double checked with multiple utilities and there is NOT a blank line at the end of the file, or any trailing spaces on any line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last read that fails to find more data will assign an empty string, so the number of entries is one more than your data. To check that use `printf "'%s'\n" "${students[@]}"`.

Comment: Just to add more information to @Janis answer, if your run the script with `bash -x students.sh` you will see that the last read will increment in 1 the array: `+ read 'students[11]'
+ echo 11
11
+ ArrayLength=12`. Since it's reading the 11th position, the ArrayLength will be 12 at the end of the operations.

Comment: Note that `read` fails when it doesn't read a newline character. It may fail and assign a non-empty string if the input ends in a non-terminated line. Like in `printf foo | read line`.